# Engine libaio not loadable

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed both libaio1 and libaio-dev packages on my Ubnutu 14.04, but after installation of "fio". Now when I want to use ioengine=libaio option of fio, I encounter with the error shown below:

fio: engine libaio not loadable

Any idea how to solve the problem without unistalling fio.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

After installing libaio-dev package on Ubuntu 14.04, please clean and build the fio again. The compilation will detect and pull your liabaio.

Steps to get over libaio issue on Ubuntu 14.04

1. Install libaio-dev
2. From you fio folder issue

   *make clean*

   and

   *make*

Comment: I had to re-run `configure`: `make clean`, `./configure` and then `make`.

Comment: why is there not "make uninstall" ? usually source gets uninstalled this way

Comment: Hi @hakkican, regarding "make uninstall", that can be a separate StackOverflow question on its own. In general, makefiles do not have "uninstall" - yet that can be done with package managers (apt / yum). One of the reasons could be that package managers are aware of dependencies between packages, so they can warn you if uninstalling will cause other things to break. The UI will offer to remove the dependent packages as well. After all, why keep software that will no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

it is help me :

```
sudo apt-get install libaio-dev
cd fio
sudo ./configure  && sudo  make  &&  sudo make install
fio ...
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.